# Windows 10 Performance Monitor System Diagnostics not starting

Tags: windows-10

I have a Windows 10 pro, and if I manually start the Data Collector under System/System Diagnostics it does not start?? I also try from cmd line with Perfmon /report a window pops out saying that will collect for 60 seconds but it never ends collecting... Is this a bug on Windows 10?

To run this report I have to manually create one in the Data Collector Sets/User with the same template, but then it reports some weird results for cpu, disk and graphics, all return 0 in the score and are marked as poor under Desktop Rating. My system has an intel i7-6700HQ 2 SSD disks (1 ssd is M.2) and 32GB of memory + 1 Geforce GTX 1060 Graphics card with 6GB.